# Trying to get multiple messages from an Azure Storage Queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have a node.js Function App which I'm trying to use to retrieve a specific message from a storage queue in order to delete it. It doesnt seem like there is a method to get a specific message by ID, so I'm trying to read all the messages, or at least 32 of them, then find the message to delete by ID.

My problem is I cant seem to figure out how to format the request to specify the number of messages to receive. I am trying to add the option "numberOfMessages" based on this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-queue/queuereceivemessageoptions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-queue-queuereceivemessageoptions-customheaders

Here is what I have right now that isn't working:

```
const response = await queueClient.receiveMessages({"numberOfMessages": 32});
context.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response.receivedMessageItems));
context.log("received messages length: " + response.receivedMessageItems.length);
```

response is:

```
[Information] response: [{"messageId":"XXXXXX","insertedOn":"2022-08-28T06:12:45.000Z","expiresOn":"2022-09-04T06:12:45.000Z","popReceipt":"XXXXXXXXX","nextVisibleOn":"2022-08-30T14:57:37.000Z","dequeueCount":858,"messageText":"XXXXXXX"}]
[Information] received messages length: 1
```

How should I be formatting the option(s)???

edit:

Here is the complete code of index.js in my function app (with redactions):

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
  const message = req.body;
  const ackType = message.ackType;

  if (ackType == 1){
      const { QueueServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-queue");

      const account = "MY_ACCOUNT_NAME";
      const accountKey = "MY_ACCOUNT_KEY";

      const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
      const queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(
          `https://${account}.queue.core.windows.net`,
          sharedKeyCredential,
          {
          retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 } // Retry options
          }
      );
      
      const queueName = "MY_QUEUE_NAME";

      const queueClient = queueServiceClient.getQueueClient(queueName);
      const response = await queueClient.receiveMessages({"numofmessages": 32});
      context.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      context.log("receivedMessageItems: " + JSON.stringify(response.receivedMessageItems));
      context.log("received messages length: " + response.receivedMessageItems.length);
  }

  context.res = {
      status: 200 /* Defaults to 200 */
  };
}
```

Here is the queue I am connecting to:
[image]

Comment: This should work. What's the response you are getting?

Comment: I am just getting a single message in the response. I have verified that there are 21 messages in the queue and they aren't invisible from a reading from somewhere else. It even gives me a different message in the response each time as if it's selecting the first one available in the queue.

Comment: I added some further context of my code to the main post.

Comment: This is weird. I just tried it and was able to get proper messages. Can you edit your question and include complete code?

Comment: Just added the complete index.js code for the function app

Comment: This is totally weird! I tried your code in a simple console app and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: Really?? I just added a picture of the storage queue I'm connecting to. I wonder what else could be the difference? I event just added 3 test messages to the queue to make sure it wasnt something with the old messages with high dequeue could. Still only get one returned.

Comment: And here's my code....https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiK85.jpg. Can you try to run the same code locally i.e. outside Function?

Comment: This is strange... I just ran my code 3 times, I got 0 messages the first time, 24 the second (first time I've seen more than 1), then 0 the third time.

Comment: By any chance multiple clients listening to the same queue ?

Comment: This could be because of 30 seconds visibility timeout. If you dequeue messages and then try to dequeue the messages again within 30 seconds you won't get any messages as the messages are hidden.

Comment: I would also recommend raising an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues.